# SQL script to set DOB based on first six digits of number on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to write a SQL script to update the DOB column based on another column where come with 12 digits of number and the first 6 digits is the DOB.

[view the sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgBjN.png)

```
Name    DOB          Identification Number
Peter   1987-01-12   870112-01-0120
John                 900921-10-5510
Alex                 670302-04-6658
```

Let's say example above, Peter's identification number is 870112-01-0120 and as mentioned the first 6 digits (YYMMDD) of his identification number is his DOB. So, Peter's DOB is 1987-01-12.

Anyone has any ideas how to write a SQL script to update the DOB based on identification number?

Thanks.

Comment: How we know it 1918 OR 2018?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which Database is it? SQL/mysql

Comment: @SandipPatel Great question! :) It should be 2018. Because the first two digits (YY) is start from 1990.

Comment: @DerekBrown yepp i totally agree StackOveflow is not a code writing service. i manage to divided YY/MM/DD to different columns by using SubString but i do not know update it to DOB column by using SQL. That's why i'm asking for help over here :)

Answer (score 1):

For your data Considered 19th century, here question is how we get which century it is, so we can apply it's logic as well instead of static `19` the century

```
SELECT
    Name,
    '19'+ LEFT(Identification_Number,2)
    +'-'+ SUBSTRING(Identification_Number,3,2)
    +'-'+ SUBSTRING(Identification_Number,5,2) AS DOB,
    Identification_Number
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should help you to update. You need to change the case condition based on your criteria for making sure its selecting current century

```
Update #temp 
    set DOB= Case When LEFT(id_number,2) >89 then  
                        '19'+ LEFT(id_number,2)
                        +'-'+ SUBSTRING(id_number,3,2)
                        +'-'+ SUBSTRING(id_number,5,2) 

                Else '20'+ LEFT(id_number,2)
                        +'-'+ SUBSTRING(id_number,3,2)
                        +'-'+ SUBSTRING(id_number,5,2) END
```